# Permission System for Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I am in the process of making a discord bot using discord.py and asyncio. The bot has commands like `kick` and `ban` which obviously should not be available to normal users.

I want to make a simple system which will detect what permissions the user's role has using `ctx.message.author` to get the user who sent the command.

I do not want the bot to detect a specific role name as these vary across servers. I also prefer not to have multiple files for the bot to keep it simple.

I have seen the discord.py documentation and various other sources but none contain examples of how to implement the various methods they talk about.

As an example, here is a single command from my bot:

```
async def kick(ctx, userName: discord.User):
    if True: #ctx.message.author.Permissions.administrator
        await BSL.kick(userName)
    else:
        permission_error = str('Sorry ' + ctx.message.author + ' you do not have permissions to do that!')
        await BSL.send_message(ctx.message.channel, permission_error)
```

Where the `if else` statement is my attempt of doing this on my own. The `#ctx.message.author.Permissions.administrator` is commented out as it does not work and replaced with `True` for testing purposes.

Thank you for any help and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions) is the name of the class.  To get the message authors permissions, you should access the [`guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions) property of the author.

```
if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
 # you could also use guild_permissions.kick_members
```

Update:

A better way to validate the permissions of the person invoking the commands is by using the [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) feature of the `commands` extension, specifically the [`has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) check.  For example, if you wanted to open your command only to people who had either the `manage_roles` permission or the `ban_members` permission, you could write your command like this:

```
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

@bot.command(name="kick", pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def _kick(ctx, member: Member):
    await bot.kick(member)

@_kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        text = "Sorry {}, you do not have permissions to do that!".format(ctx.message.author)
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, text)
```

Comment: I know the initial question does not mention it but is there any way to check the message author's ID so that I can have access to all commands regardless of role?

Comment: `Member` is a subclass of `User`, so you should be able to just do `author.id`

Comment: I got this error :  `File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dicordBot.py", line 25, in clear
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id('344812358868402176'):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: `author.id` will return the id.  You should do `author.id == '123...'`

Answer (score 4):

You could also use decorators.

```
@bot.command(name = "Kick")
@bot.has_permissions(kick_user = True)
@bot.bot_has_permissions(kick_user = True)
async def _kick(ctx, member: Member):
    #Do stuff...
```

The advantage of checking user and bot permissions means it is easier to handle errors from either providing useful "Insufficient Permission" error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The tips found the accepted answer may not work:

1. There may be compatibility issues with the rewrite version of the discord.py library and the pre-rewrite versions, which remain non-obsolete, non-deprecated, and still in use.
2. The bot should also check it's own permissions, to rule out one reason for the error.
3. If there is an error, or permissions for the bot itself are invalid, the bot should say something, correct?
4. Something needs to be implemented to prevent the bot from attempting to work this command in a DM or group context. It will almost always error.

I propose the following solution for pre-rewrite (assuming you use the command extension):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time
@bot.command(pass_context=True,description="Kicks the given member. Please ensure both the bot and the command invoker have the permission 'Kick Members' before running this command.")
async def kick(ctx, target:discord.Member):
    """(GUILD ONLY) Boot someone outta the server. See 's!kick' for more."""
    if not str(ctx.message.channel).startswith("Direct Message with "):
        msg=await bot.say("Checking perms...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if ctx.message.server.me.server_permissions.kick_members:
            if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.kick_members:
                await bot.edit_message(msg,new_content="All permissions valid, checking issues with target...")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                if target==ctx.message.server.owner:
                    await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="All permissions are correct, but you're attempting to kick the server owner, whom you can't kick no matter how hard you try. Whoops!")
                else:
                    if target==ctx.message.server.me:
                        await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="Whoops! All permissions are corrent, but you just tried to make me kick myself, which is not possible. Perhaps you meant someone else, not poor me?")
                    else:
                        await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="All permissions correct, and no issues with target being self or server owner, attempting to kick.")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        try:
                            await bot.kick(target)
                            await bot.edit_message(msg, ":boom: BAM! ***kicc'd***")
                        except Exception:
                            await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="I was unable to kick the passed member. The member may have a higher role than me, I may have crashed into a rate-limit, or an unknown error may have occured. In that case, try again.")
            else:
                await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="I've the correct permissions, {}, but you do not. Perhaps ask for them?").format(ctx.message.author.mention)
        else:
            await bot.edit_message(msg, new_content="I'm just a poor bot with no permissions. Could you kindly grant me the permission `Kick Members`? Thanks! :slight_smile:")
    else:
        await bot.say("'Tis a DM! This command is for servers only... try this again in a server maybe? :slight_smile:")
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Based on the current version of discord.py, using discord.ext.commands, you can do this:

> Replace all <> with what it says.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "<this can be whatever you want>", intents = discord.intents.all())
#make sure to enable all intents in the discord dev portal. I use all intents to make things simple.

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(<permission> = True)
async def ban():
   #the ban commands go here
```

The permission has to be **exactly** like how it says in the api documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions).
These permission ID's are for discord, but they are the same for discord.ext.
The ID for banning is `ban_members`. In the decorator `@commands.has_permissions`, remember to **NOT** put the ID in quotes. Also remember to add `= True` to the end of the id.