# Permission Check Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot for basic moderation which does `kick`, `ban` and `mute` for now at least. But the problem is other members can use it too. I want only a few specified role who can use it.

Don't want to work on it depending on the `@role` either because the name of the roles across different servers aren't the same. Also wanting to keep the bot as simple as possible.

Now, I started out as this:

```
@client.command(name='ban')
async def mod_ban(member: discord.User):
    try:
        await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=0)
        await client.say('**{0}** has been banned.'.format(str(member)))
    except Exception as error:
        await client.say(error)
```

But any member can use the commands then. So, tried follow this one = [Permission System for Discord.py Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612603/permission-system-for-discord-py-bot) and ended up with this:

```
@client.command(name='ban')
async def mod_ban(context, member: discord.User):
    if context.message.author.server_premission.administrator:
        try:
            await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=0)
            await client.say('**{0}** has been banned.'.format(str(member)))
        except Exception as error:
            await client.say(error)
    else:
        await client.say('Looks like you don\'t have the perm.')
```

Which lands me with this error: ;-;

```
raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

Also, besides `context.message.author.server_premission.administrator` I don't only want the roles with Admin perm to use this command. I also want a few other roles with have few perms like `manage message`, `manage roles` etc. to use to command too.

Thanks in advance for the help! Also, sorry if I've missed anything stupid or silly ;-;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't passing the context into the coroutine in your second example (and as @Andrei suggests, you can  only ban members):

```
@client.command(name='ban', pass_context=True)
async def mod_ban(context, member: discord.Member):
    ...
```

Also, I should probably update [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613050/6779307).  In the context of commands, you can use the very powerful [checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) built into `discord.ext.commands` to do a lot of this for you. [`has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) does exactly what you're looking for, validating that the user has any of the necessary permissions.

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure

@client.command(name='ban', pass_context=true)
@has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True)
async def mod_ban(ctx, member: discord.Member):        
    await client.ban(member, delete_message_days=0)
    await client.say('**{0}** has been banned.'.format(str(member)))

@mod_ban.error
async def mod_ban_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Looks like you don't have the perm.")
```

Comment: `from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions` throws this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'MissingPermissions'`

Comment: @THEBlueBRAD.M Looks like on async it'll raise `CheckFailure` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the discord.py documentation [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) is not the same as [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member).

Try to change

```py
async def mod_ban(context, member: discord.User):
```

to

```py
async def mod_ban(context, member: discord.Member):
```

Comment: `Member` is a subclass of `User`, but you're right that a `User` won't have the necessary attributes for `ban` to determine which server they are banned from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.py rewrite, you can use checks ([Discord.py rewrite checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#checks))
Which (obviusly) checks for certain things suchs as roles or permissions on the command invoker

You can use both of this decorators, below your first decorator

```
@commands.has_role("rolename"/roleid)
@commands.has_any_role("rolename"/roleid,"rolename"/roleid,"rolename"/roleid ...)
```

Where rolename is a string containing the EXACT name of the role, letter by letter and space by space, and roleid is the id of the role, which, in case it's mentionable, you can get it by typing @rolename on any of your server chatrooms

Note how you must use the second decorator if you want to pass more than one role to check