# discord.py handling multiple exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, try-except

In my try block I have added 2 exceptions. One if the bot does not have permission and another exception for everything else. However, the code below does not show the exception for permission error instead uses the other one.

```py
@commands.command(no_pm=True)
    async def mal(self, *, srch=None):
        try:
            if srch is None:
                await self.Nao.say('You need to provide an anime name')
                return
            if " " in srch:
                srch.replace(" ", "/")
            url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime/?q=' + srch + '&page=1'
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            malEmbed = discord.Embed(title=data['results'][0]['title'], description=data['results'][0]['synopsis'], url=data['results'][0]['url'], color=0xff00ff)
            malEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=data['results'][0]['image_url'])
            malEmbed.add_field(name='Episodes: ', value=data['results'][0]['episodes'])
            malEmbed.add_field(name='Rated: ', value=data['results'][0]['rated'])
            await self.Nao.say(embed=malEmbed)
        except PermissionError:
            await self.Nao.say('I need permission to embed links to do this.')
            return
        except:
            await self.Nao.say('There was an error. My developers have been alerted!')
```

I have removed the bots permission to embed links meaning it should respond with the exception for `PermissionError` however is returning "There was an error. My developers have been alerted!" instead.

Comment: which discord.py are you using?

Comment: Also, can you provide a full working example? requests is not defined as of now and so for me, this error supersedes the PermissionError (the bot never tries to embed a link before this error occurs). As youre using the commands extension I also suggest you take a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612603/permission-system-for-discord-py-bot
Its a much better way of handling permissions and exceptions imo

Comment: That’s the async branch and that command works just the error I stated

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix for the error. Instead of having it try and catching the no permission. I made it first check the bots permission and if it has permissions it will run the reset and if not it will jump straight to the else statement

```py
    @commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def mal(self, ctx, *, srch=None):
        if ctx.message.server.me.server_permissions.embed_links:
            try:
                if srch is None:
                    await self.Nao.say('You need to provide an anime name')
                    return
                if " " in srch:
                    srch.replace(" ", "/")
                url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime/?q=' + srch + '&page=1'
                response = requests.get(url)
                data = response.json()
                malEmbed = discord.Embed(title=data['results'][0]['title'], description=data['results'][0]['synopsis'], url=data['results'][0]['url'], color=0xff00ff)
                malEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=data['results'][0]['image_url'])
                malEmbed.add_field(name='Episodes: ', value=data['results'][0]['episodes'])
                malEmbed.add_field(name='Rated: ', value=data['results'][0]['rated'])
                await self.Nao.say(embed=malEmbed)
            except:
                await self.Nao.say('There was an error. My developers have been alerted!')
        else:
            await self.Nao.say('I need permission to embed links to do this.')
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make a permission list with role ids:

```
administrative_roles = [ 856116059912011777 , 924800792773398548 , 929356299777490994]
```

and do the check like this:

```
for arole in administrative_roles:
   if arole in [role.id for role in ctx.author.roles]:
       (your command)
   else:
       await.ctx.channel.send('No enaugh permission')
```