# How can I make the bot say something when someone tries to kick a higher admin or himself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

When someone tries to kick a higher in rank admin the bot does nothing not even an error, I want it instead to return a text into chat. Also if someone tries to kick/ban himself it works, how can I disable that? Thanks
here is the code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.channel.send(f"User {member} got kicked")

 @client.command()
 @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
 async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"User {member} got banned")
```

Comment: Does this help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612603/permission-system-for-discord-py-bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can compare top_role of the members

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if ctx.author.top_role <= member.top_role:
        await ctx.send("The person you tried to kick has equal or higher role than you")
        return
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"User {member} got kicked")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if ctx.author.top_role <= member.top_role:
        await ctx.send("The person you tried to ban has equal or higher role than you")
        return
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"User {member} got banned")
```